# Redirecionamento após post em api com axios em ReactJS

Tags: react, login, react-router, react-dom, reactive-programming

Bom dia,

Estou tentando criar uma tela de login em ReactJS onde é feito um post em uma uma api, após enviar o e-mail e a senha do usuário,  a API devolve o token de authenticação JWT.

Post na API em meu componente (Entrar.js)

```
 axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://localhost:44332/api/token',
            data: corpo,
            config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
        })
            .then(function (res) {

                // salva o token no localstorage
                localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);


            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

Essa é a forma correta de fazer isso? Como posso redirecinar meu usuário para outro componente. ex: dashboard.js

Grato, abs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando `react-router-dom` você pode usar `this.props.history.push('/your-path')`. `/your-path` é o caminho que você definiu nas suas rotas que renderiza o componente de dashboard.